# Notation regarding differential form and vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, notation

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $X,Y$ are vector fields on $M$, $\omega$ be a $1$ form on $M$. Then, following result is quoted with out proof and with out explanation of notation,

$$d\omega(X,Y)=X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y]).$$

Let $p\in M$, then, I guess

- $d\omega(X,Y)(p)$ means $(d\omega)(p)(X(p),Y(p))\in \mathbb{R}$
- $\omega([X,Y])(p)$ means $\omega(p)([X,Y](p))\in \mathbb{R}$.

I am not able to guess what could be the definition of $X(\omega(Y))(p)$.

Any reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let me make some recalls.

Let $X$ be a vector field on $M$ and $f\colon M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function, then by definition, one has:
$$X(f)\colon M\rightarrow\mathbb{R},x\mapsto T_xf(X(x)).$$
On a side note, this construction is used along with [Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma) to prove that one has a bijective correspondence between vector fields on $M$ and derivations $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ *i.e.* endomorphism $\delta$ of the real vector space $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ such that for all $f,g\in C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$, one has:
$$\delta(fg)=\delta(f)g+f\delta(g).$$
This bijective correspondence is of central interest when defining the [Lie bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields) of two vector fields.

Coming back to your question.

If $\omega$ is differential form of degree $1$ on $M$ and $Y$ is a vector field on M, then $\omega(Y)\colon M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is defined as:
$$\omega(Y)(x)=\omega_x(Y(x)).$$
Therefore, $X(\omega(Y))$ is the function obtained from $\omega(Y)$ applying the derivation associated to $X$.

I cannot help providing a proof for the identity you stated, as it is a frequently used one.

> **Proposition.** Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, let $X,Y\in\Gamma(TM)$ and let $\omega\in\Lambda^1T^*M$, then one has:
>   $$\mathrm{d}\omega(X,Y)=X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y]).$$

**Proof.** First, let define $\alpha\colon\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(TM)\rightarrow C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ by:
$$\alpha(X,Y):=X(\omega(Y))-Y(\omega(X))-\omega([X,Y]).$$
Notice that $\alpha$ is a $C^\infty(M,R)$-bilinear map using the $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$-linearity of $\omega$ and the fact that $X(\cdot)$, $Y(\cdot)$ are derivations, along with the following identity:
$$[fX,gY]=fg[X,Y]+fX(g)Y-gY(f)X.$$
Besides, since $\mathrm{d}\omega$ is a differential form of degree $2$, it is also a $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$-bilinear map.

To conclude, notice that the desired equality is local and it therefore suffices to work in a chart of $M$:
$$(U,(x_1,\ldots,x_n)).$$ 
This chart induces $(TU,(\partial_{x_1},\ldots,\partial_{x_n}))$ a chart of $TM$ and $(T^*U,(\mathrm{d}x_1,\ldots,\mathrm{d}x_n))$ a chart of $T^*M$. Hence, we can write:
$$\omega_{\vert U}=\sum_{k=1}^n\omega_k\mathrm{d}x_k.\tag{1}$$
In particular, one gets the following expression:
$$\mathrm{d}\omega_{\vert U}=\sum_{k,\ell=1}^n\partial_{x_\ell}\omega_k\mathrm{d}x_{\ell}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_k.\tag{2}$$
Recall that any element of $\Gamma(TU)$ is a $C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$-linear combination of $\partial_{x_i}$ and the problem boils down to:
$$\mathrm{d}\omega(\partial_{x_i},\partial_{x_j})=\alpha(\partial_{x_i},\partial_{x_j}).$$
Which is almost immediate, since:
$$\mathrm{d}x_{\ell}\wedge\mathrm{d}x_k(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\begin{vmatrix}\mathrm{d}x_\ell(\partial_i)&{d}x_\ell(\partial_j)\\\mathrm{d}x_k(\partial_i)&\mathrm{d}x_k(\partial_j)\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\delta_{i,\ell}&\delta_{j,\ell}\\\delta_{i,k}&\delta_{j,k}\end{vmatrix}=\delta_{i,\ell}\delta_{j,k}-\delta_{i,k}\delta_{j,\ell},$$
so that pluging in $(2)$, one gets:
$$\mathrm{d}\omega(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\partial_{x_i}\omega_j-\partial_{x_j}\omega_i.$$
Besides, from $(1)$, one has $\omega(\partial_i)=\omega_i$, $\omega(\partial_j)=\omega_j$ and using [Schwarz's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives), one gets:
$$\alpha(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\partial_{x_i}\omega_j-\partial_{x_j}\omega_i.$$
Whence the result. $\Box$

**Remark.** Let $V$ be a real vector space of finite dimension and let $\xi_V$ be the trivial vector bundle over $M$ with fiber $V$, then one actually defines the exterior derivative of differential forms with values in $\xi_V$ *i.e.* sections of $\Lambda^rT^*M\otimes\xi_V$ by this precise formula.

The proposition then tells us that if $V=\mathbb{R}$, the two definitions coincide.

We only did the work for $r=1$, but the formula [extends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#In_terms_of_invariant_formula) in a natural fashion to greater $r$.

Answer (score 1):

A $k$-form on $M$ is a map taking $p \in M$ to $\omega(p) \equiv \omega_p \colon (T_pM)^k \to \Bbb R$, which depends smoothly on $p$. In particular, if $\omega$ is a $1$-form and $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, then $\omega(X)$ is a smooth function taking $p \in M$ to $\omega_p(X_p) \in \Bbb R$, and similarly for $k$-forms in general. So your guesses are correct. Also, if "everything is fixed" except the point, you'll get a smooth function on $M$, as in $$M \ni p \mapsto X_p(\omega(Y)) \in \Bbb R,$$since $X_p$ is a tangent vector acting in the smooth function $\omega(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you. I got it :).

Comment: You can look [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2248873/exterior-derivative-and-lie-derivative/2248888#2248888) in case you get in trouble proving the formula.